# How do you integrate an Expo app to use the OS "Settings" page to manage settings?

Tags: react-native, expo

Is it possible to set up an Expo app to use the iOS and Android settings to manage application settings?

I know how to open up the settings:

```js
import * as Application from "expo-application";
import * as IntentLauncher from "expo-intent-launcher";
import { Linking, Platform } from "react-native";

function openAppSettings() {
  if (Platform.OS === "ios") {
    Linking.openURL("app-settings:");
  } else {
    IntentLauncher.startActivityAsync(
      IntentLauncher.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS,
      { data: "package:" + Application.applicationId }
    );
  }
}
```

But I can't find information on how to add custom app settings.